# Comparar dois drawables

Tags: android

Sempre que clico no meu ImageButton quero comparar a imagem dele com o drawable que tenho nos resources.

```
imag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

    ImageButton photo = (ImageButton)view;

            Drawable imagem= photo.getBackground();
            Drawable cartOff = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cart_off);
            Drawable cart = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cart);


            if(imagem.equals(cart))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), " certo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(imagem.equals(cartOff))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), " errado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Só que não está a funcionar, não devolve nenhum dos `Toasts`

Answer (score 1):

Você está criando instâncias diferentes do seu drawable e os comparando , nunca serão iguais pois estão alocados em endereços de memória diferentes.

Utilize o método `getConstanteState` para realizar essa comparação.

```
getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cart_off).equals(photo.getBackground().getConstantState())
```